# how to understand the same iterating-var in nested loop?

Tags: python-2.7, loops, iterator

```
for i in range(5):
    print 'out-i',i
    for i in range(3):
        print 'inner-i',i
```

I'm confused to the two iterating-var 'i'. The second var 'i' is any connection with the first?

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(3):
```

I can't clearly find out the difference between the two codes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two codes but the name of the iterators used. The first one is not recommended as you cannot access the outer `i` from inside the second loop